Как сделать заявку на пополнение в тг боте?
У меня есть тг бот на aiogram==2.25., мне надо по команде создавать заявку на платеж (CyberMoneyCRM - платежная система), у них есть своя документация и я не очень понял её
ссылка на docks - https://cyber.money/crm/payment/api/docs
Код создания заявки:
API_TOKEN = 'xxxxxx'
CYBER_MONEY_API_URL = 'https://cyber.money/api/v1/ast/'
CYBER_MONEY_API_KEY = 'xxxxxxx'

# Хранилище для отслеживания времени создания заявки
request_creation_times = {}


import requests

def create_request(amount, payment_method, card_type=None):
    url = f"{CYBER_MONEY_API_URL}request"
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f"{CYBER_MONEY_API_KEY}",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    payload = {
        'sum': amount,
        'payment_method': payment_method,
    }
    if card_type:
        payload['card_type'] = card_type
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)  # Используем POST
        response.raise_for_status()  # Проверка на HTTP ошибки
        print(f"Response status code: {response.status_code}")
        print(f"Response content: {response.text}")
        return response.json()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as http_err:
        print(f"HTTP error occurred: {http_err}")
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Other error occurred: {err}")
    return None


@dp.message_handler(commands=['pay'])
async def pay(message: types.Message):
    amount = 100  # Сумма в рублях
    payment_method = 'ccard'  # Способ оплаты
    card_type = 'sberbank'  # Тип карты (если применимо)

    result = create_request(amount, payment_method, card_type)
    if result and 'request_id' in result:
        request_id = result['request_id']
        # Сохраняем время создания заявки
        request_creation_times[request_id] = datetime.now()
        await message.reply(f"Заявка создана. ID: {request_id}. Подтвердите оплату командой /confirm {request_id}")
    else:
        await message.reply("Не удалось создать заявку.")

выдает ошибку - {"error":{"code":405,"message":"The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."}}
